# how to split a dataframe in two from a specific value on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have this dataframe:

[image]

In row 84 it changes from a negative value in the 'position' column to positive.

I need to split the data frame into two at this point (before and after position=0)

I tried using

`idx = run_1[run_1['Position_(m)']>0].index
 dfs = np.split(df, idx)`

but it split on every instance where >0 and if I use idx[0] it says:

ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division

Note: I only need one split, "before and after," I have looked through other similar questions to mine but most deal with multiple splits and I'm unable to re-use the code sugested for a single split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Boolean mask to do this:

```
before = run_9[run_9['Position_(m)']<0]
after = run_9[run_9['Position_(m)']>0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was overthinking it. I really appreciate the help.